# Redirection from a directory to a file

Tags: php, redirect

I have a problem with my php project.
I hosted my project, but when I write in the URL, for example www.example.com/admin, it shows me all the files in that folder.
What I want to do is redirecting that url to a file, so when i write in the url: www.example.com/admin it should take me to www.example.com/login.php .
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It sounds like, to start, you have directory indexing turned on (which is why you are seeing a list of files). Could you please edit your question and provide some additional information about your web server (e.g. Nginx or Apache) and whether it should always redirect from admin -> login.php if the user is logged in?  This will help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be create an `index.php` file inside the `admin` folder. Usually, this is enough to tell Apache to not listen the content of this folder and instead run this index file instead. To redirect it to another page, you can use the PHP `header()` function like the following snippet:

```php
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/login.php');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already have a index.php file in the admin folder, but is still opening the files.

Comment: Can you include in your question information about your web server (e.g. Apache, Nginx)  configuration? Or if you are using some service to publish your application like Heroku